# Is there an alternative to Json.dump which outputs an Array?

Tags: json, ruby

I am creating a PUT request, which [requires a JSON object Array](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/business-rules/macros/#update-macro) to be sent in the payload. I have put the data into an array, and have confirmed it's Array class, but when it is supplied as an argument to Json.dump() it is outputted as a String Object, which causes a 500 Internal Server Error, is there an alternative method of pushing the data, which will keep it in its original format?

```
  def call_api

  url = URI("url.zendesk.com/api/v2/macros/update_many")

  https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
  https.use_ssl = true

  request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(url)
  request["Authorization"] = "Basic ="
  request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
  request.body = JSON.dump(@data) #outputs a string, should be a json array
  response = https.request(request)
end
```

Reponse => `#<Net::HTTPInternalServerError 500 Internal Server Error readbody=true>`

Comment: What is the body of the response?

Comment: @Schwern It's "{\"status\":\"500\",\"error\":\"Internal Server Error\"}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...but when it is supplied as an argument to Json.dump() it is outputted as a String Object

By definition, JSON is a string. It takes data and turns it into a string which can then be turned back into data. This is [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). So that part is fine.

You probably need to add a scheme to your URL like `https`. Newer versions of Net::HTTP won't even accept a URI without a scheme. That might be the source of the 500 error.

Looking at [the API documentation](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/business-rules/macros/#json-format), the proper URL ends in `.json`.

```
url = URI("https://url.zendesk.com/api/v2/macros/update_many.json")
```

It does not take an array, it takes an object like so. Getting this format wrong should result in a 400 Bad Request.

```
@data = {
  "macros": [
    {
      "active": false,
      "id": 25
    },
    {
      "id": 23,
      "position": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, there exists [an official Zendesk Ruby API client](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_rb) which might be easier to use.